# Unable to write file to shared folder in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am trying to write a csv file to a shared drive and it doesn't seem to work

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("E:\\test\\test.csv", fileContents);
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("Z:\\test\\test.csv", fileContents);
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("\\\\10.3.22.11\\path\\test.csv", fileContents);
```

Now the first line works, but the second line and third line don't work.

For the third line, the exception is "Access to the path is denied", but the shared path does not have any login required. I tried mapping the shared path to Z drive and tried to write the file using second line, the exception for that one is

```
Could not find a part of the path 'Z:\test\test.csv'.
```

Comment: 1) IIS does not support mapped drives. 2) When UNC path fails, capture SMB packets and learn what might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if you want to let the IIS access the file share, you should make sure your IIS application pool identity has modified to  Network Service account or use custom domain user and make sure you has added enough permission on the shared folder, since Network service and local system both appear on the network as the computer account (DOMAIN\computer$).

Details steps as below:

Modify the application pool identity:

1.Open the IIS management console.

2.Select the application pool and advanced setting

[image]

3.Modify the application pool identity to use custom domain account.

[image]

Modify the folder permission:

1.Right click the computer and click the property, you will find your computer name as below:

[image]

2.Go to your shared folder server, right click the folder and click property. Then you could add your server's account to it like this (Domain\Servername$)

[image]